# A Problem about the Artin Symbol

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathfrak{p} = 7 \mathbb{Z}$. I found that $7 \mathcal{O}_K = (2\sqrt{2}+1)(-2\sqrt{2}+1)$. The Artin symbol $\left[ \frac{K/\mathbb{Q}}{(2\sqrt{2}+1)} \right]$ is defined as the unique $\sigma$ in ${\rm Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ such that
$$
\sigma(\alpha) = \alpha^{\text{Norm} (7\mathbb{Z})} = \alpha^7 \bmod (2\sqrt{2}+1).
$$
Here, $\bmod (2\sqrt{2}+1)$ means that the difference belongs to the ideal $(2\sqrt{2}+1) = (2\sqrt{2}+1)\mathcal{O}_K = (2\sqrt{2}+1)\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$.

Via Sage, I found that $\sigma$ is the identity and if I choose $\alpha = \frac{2}{5} \sqrt{2}$ I get $$\alpha^{\text{Norm} (7\mathbb{Z})} - \alpha = \alpha^7 - \alpha = -\frac{30226}{78125}\sqrt{2} \neq 0  \mod (2\sqrt{2}+1).$$

So, what is the point that I am missing?

Comment: What you're missing is that 30226 is divisible by 7, so $\alpha^7 - \alpha$ is divisible by $7$ and thus also by $2\sqrt{2}+1$.

Comment: You don't need Sage to determine $\sigma$. The question is to determine the sign in $\sigma(\sqrt2)=\pm\sqrt2$. But $(\sqrt2)^7=8\sqrt2\equiv\sqrt2\pmod 7$. Hence the same holds modulo both factors of $7$ as well. Also $-\sqrt2\not\equiv2 8\sqrt2$.

Comment: @KCd thank you sir.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks and somehow Sage returns 'false' for the following:
$((2/5)*a)^7 - (2/5)*a \text{ in } \text{K.ideal}(2*a+1)$
where $a$ was defined as the generator: $a = \sqrt(2)$.

Comment: That is probably because $(2/5)\sqrt2$ is not an algebraic integer. Hence it cannot be an element of any ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ either. Why did you think it should be in that ideal?

Comment: When we write $\bmod (2\sqrt{2}+1)$, I think that it is $(2\sqrt{2}+1) = (2\sqrt{2}+1)\mathcal{O}_K = (2\sqrt{2}+1)\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ so it's an integral ideal. Is it a fractional ideal? Thanks.